# Consultation on creating views in CnosDB

Tags: cnosdb

MySQL:

```
-- Create
CREATE VIEW employee_view AS
SELECT id, name, department
FROM employees
WHERE department = 'IT';

-- Select
SELECT * FROM employee_view;

-- Update
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW employee_view AS
SELECT id, name, department
FROM employees
WHERE department = 'HR';

-- Drop
DROP VIEW employee_view;
```

How is the view feature implemented in CnosDB? Please provide documentation or examples. Thank you.